# Безопасная передача данных сервер-клиент

Tags: php, ssl, rsa, криптография

Как можно реализовать безопасную передпчу сервер <-> клиент. Сообшения от клиента к серверу можно шифровать RSA, вшить паблик ключ в клиент а на сервере приватный. Проблемы начинабтся когда нужно передать данный от сераера клиенту. Если использовать такой же вприант то клиент можно отдебажить и выдернуть из него заветный приватный ключ и сообшения от сервера клиенту будут скомпрометированны. Как быть?

Comment: Как вы вырвете приватный ключ из клиента, если он на сервере?

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли. Я пишу "если использовать такой же вариант". Т.е. другаяпара RSA  ключей, паблик на сераере а приват в клиенте. То вот этот приват можно вытащить. Это когда сообщенте идет от сервера к клиенту

Comment: Для начала почитайте про TLS, который нынче работает на каждом веб-сайте и обеспечивает эту самую безопасную передачу сервер-клиент

Comment: @LorDo прошу прощения. Почитайте про симметричное шифрование

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно чем не устроила стандартная реализация SSL соединения? Но если не устроила и хочется изобрести свой велосипед, то делается это так

1. Клиент получает открытый ключ сервера
2. Сервер генерирует сессионный ключ для **симметричного** шифрования, шифрует этот ключ своим приватным ключом и отправляет клиенту
3. Клиент расшифровывает этот ключ публичным ключом сервера
4. Весь трафик на клиента и обратно шифруется этим сессионным ключом

Это все работает при условии, что сервер доверяет клиенту. Если не доверяет, то клиент должен пятым пунктом, в закрытом канале, доказать, что это именно он

Comment: Разве можно зашифровать сообщение ПРИВАТНЫМ ключем и расшифровать его ОТКРЫТЫМ ключем? RSA например

Comment: @LorDo Можно. Если поменять их местами. Именно так работает ЭЦП. Есть всего лишь пара EncryptKey/DecryptKey. Какой из этих ключей вы делаете приватным, а какой публичным - это вы определяете сами

Comment: Придумал такой формат интересно мнение: 1) В клиент зашит открытый ключ RSA. 2) Клиент генерирует ключ семмитричного шифровпния. 3) Клиент отправляет на сервер  ключ_семитричного_шифрованич+данные зашифрованные открытым ключем RSA. 4) Сервер расшифровывает сообщение от клиента приватным ключем RSA. 5) Сервер обрабатывает данные и генерирует ответ, который он шифрует симитричным шифрованием AES ключем переданным от клиента. Ответ возвращается клиенту. 6) Клиент получает ответ сервера и расшифровывает его ключем симитричного шифрования который он и сгенерировал. 7) Сеанс окончен.

Comment: @LorDo 3 пункт не понял вообще. Может имелось в виду "отправляет сессионный ключ **зашифрованный** открытым ключом?

Comment: Клиенту нужно отправить какие-то данные серверу. Клиент отправляет эти данные вместе с сессионным ключем, который булет использоваться для шифрации ответа сервера. Данные и сессиюнный ключ шифруются открытым ключем RSA.

Comment: @LorDo Тогда я не вижу принципиальных отличий с той схемой, что привел я